# Can't connect to Play Store. Which app keeps modifying my "hosts" file?

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, google-play-services, hosts

So I am using a rooted Galaxy S6. I am familiar with the hosts file in the Android system and how it works. I modify the hosts file to block ads every once and a while.

Recently, I haven't been able to connect to the Play Store. When I looked this up, I find out the "hosts" file has been edited. I see this line: *127.244.77.91 android.clients.google.com*.

According to the Internet, the solution is to simply put a hashtag to exclude that server or whatever. But even when I do that, the same entry is added below the one I excluded!

Which app keeps modifying the hosts file? Is it the Google Play Store? Is it Google Play Services? What about the Google Play Services Framework?

How can I prevent the hosts file from being edited without my permission?

Comment: You're rooted, so any apps you've granted Root access can modify the file in question.  Without access to your device, we cannot tell you what app is doing this, don't know what you even have installed.  I would start at looking at any apps you've granted Root access to.

Comment: I will show the list of apps I have granted root access to. Hold on..